Laplace transform for linear circuits - Initial value problem with generalized impedances?
I'm currently attempting to generalize a trivial circuit composed of from simple \$R\$, \$C\$ to more complex parasitic \$R\$, \$L\$, \$C\$ modeling of real components. This would be in the context of high voltage impulse modeling. I generally like working with Laplace transforms and generalized impedances, but I find myself in need of inserting a capacitor (which would be replaced by a generalized impedance \$Z(s)\$) with initial voltage and model the natural evolution at the close of a switch. I'm probably just somewhat rusty with my Laplace solutions...
This would be relatively simple if I had used a simple \$sC \cdot V - v(0)\$, etc., but the equation now is of the form \$Z(s) \cdot I(s)\$ with \$Z(s)\$ being modeled as in the schematic (ignore component values).
How would I insert the voltage initial condition in this case? Is the \${L}\{f^n\} = s^nF(s) - s^{n-1}f(0)\$, etc., still applicable, going into the integral \$\frac{f(0)}{s}\$?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
EDIT to make things clearer - I have a network to analyze with Laplace transform, There are no sources except for a pre-charged capacitor. Usually, I wouldn't use the generalized impedances \$Z(s)\$ to model the components, I'd use the single I/V relationships for the reactive components which would yield a pretty trivial circuit.
I'm interested instead in generalizing the circuit with generalized impedances, while still being able to insert the initial conditions for the charge of my capacitor. How can I insert the v(t=0) condition in a capacitor?
e.g. for the element displayed \$ V(s) = Z(s)I(s) = \frac{R+sL}{LCs^2+RCs+1} I(s) \$
Can we use the mentioned rule for \$v(t=0)\$ as
\$ V(s) - \frac{v(0)}{s}= \frac{R+sL}{LCs^2+RCs+1} I(s) - \frac{v(0)}{s} \$

I'm not entirely clear on this. Are you asking about a case where you want the source-free evolution of the voltage across this Ztotal given initial conditions for the capacitor and inductor? Or is there a source somewhere? Is this supposed to be a more generalized approach with many initial conditions and sometimes sources and sometimes not? Because if you are supposed to analyze these, in general, then I think you need a good book on graph theory that uses Laplace, such as Graph Theory with Applications to Engineering and Computer Science by Narsingh Deo.

Thank you for the help. I edited the post to clear up some things. I dont have any sources, just a pre-charged capacitor. It would be helpful to know the generic procedure with these kinds of problems though. Thank you for the book recommendation as well!

The inductor will also have a separate initial condition.
